# How to correctly create a database using entity framework code first approach

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

After playing around with entity framework code first approach to generate a database, I am still not sure what the correct way is, the only way I was able to generate a database is using migrations, so after setting up the models I need, I use the package manager and do:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

and then:

```
Add-Migration Initial
```

Finally:

```
Update-Database
```

I've seen many tutorials similar to this one:

[Code First to a New Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj193542.aspx)

that talks about setting up the models and after running the project, the database appears without using migration at all, I am quite confused, so here are my questions:

1. Is the database created after the using statement? so in the tutorial above:

   ```
   using (var db = new BloggingContext())
   ```
2. Is migration generally used for updating the database only?
3. In your opinion what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Is the database created after the using statement? so in the tutorial above:**

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
```

That almost works, but you need to add additional syntax that causes EF to execute something to the database, for example.

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
{
    db.YourDbSetProperty.Any();
}
```

**2. Is migration generally used for updating the database only?**

Yes, with EF migration, you will be able to apply the changes you made from code to the database without dropping and recreating the database.

But it can also be used to generate the database upgrade script.

**3. In your opinion what is the best way?**

This is primarily opinion based, you could do either way, but for development purpose on local machine, I usually drop and recreate the database from code, not using migration syntax.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough on the second question, what I mean is is it fine to use migration to initialize/create the database and not just updating the database?, is there any drawbacks using it this way?

Comment: yes it's fine, no drawback just different strategy, migrations is usually used for production, for initial development we hardly use it, just code then F5, Boom!! the database is created